# Open data stream (FTP AUTH TLS)

Tags: c#, ssl, channel

I communicate with a FTP server that requires `AUTH TLS`.
So I created a `NetworkStream` and sent `AUTH TLS`. After this I created a `SslStream` with the `NetworkStream` as `InnerStream` and sent `USER user` and `PASS pass`.

After this, I can use `PWD`, etc., but when I want to download a file with `RETR`, the server want a new channel.

How can I open this channel to receive the file data?

Comment: Do you have particular reasons to reinvent the wheel? There are plenty of FTPS client components available on the market.

Comment: Then I suggest that you create an FTP client and then add TLS to it. To open data connection you optionally send PASV command, then PORT command, next REST command (optional) and finally you call RETR and connect or receive connection (depending on whether you use passive or active mode). RFC 959 has sequence diagrams. TLS for data channel is negotiated after the data channel is established, and there will also be some surprises there.

Comment: Yes, but the server always says: "SSL/TLS required in the data channel"... But when I send "AUTH TLS\n" (on the data channel), nothing happens.

Comment: You just start handshake on data channel. Don't send any commands there. The problem is that some buggy servers expect you to act as TLS server when your FTPS client is in Active mode, while most will provide a server and see you as a TLS client (even in Active mode).

Comment: What should I do? Is the server the only problem?

Comment: As I mentioned, you just start the handshake on the data channel.

Comment: Start the handshake? Isn't this included when I use the "Connect"-method (TcpClient)?

Comment: I am talking about TLS handshake, which is not done automatically when you connect using TCP transport.

Comment: How could I do this? With the "AuthenticateAsClient"-method (SslStream)?

Comment: How did you do this for command channel?